# TYPO3 9.5: tt_content with language setting "all languages" (-1) not working in default language

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I upgraded a TYPO3 installation from 8.6 to 9.5. On pages with contents with language setting "all languages" those elements are not shown in frontend.

It seems that in `ContentObjectRenderer->getQueryConstraints` the constraint  `AND (tt_content.sys_language_uid in (0,-1))` is only added, if i open the same page in other languages. In the default language it's always `AND (tt_content.sys_language_uid = 0)`. In TYPO3 8.5 the expected constraint is also added in the default language.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? My relevant TypoScript setup looks like this:

```
config {
    linkVars = L(0-1)
    defaultGetVars.L = 0
    sys_language_uid = 0
    sys_language_mode = content_fallback
    sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
}
```

EDIT:

I made some additional tests and it seems, that extbase and even the RECORDS TypoScript object type works as expected. The problem only occurs if CONTENT object type is used (which is the case for `styles.content.get` in EXT:frontend)

EDIT:

I created an issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87093

Comment: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86762

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug, have a look here >> https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86762

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think this issue deals with my problem. The reported issue deals with problems in the site configuration. My problem is specific to tt_content/ContentObjectRenderer and occurs, no matter if there is a site configuration or not.
I will make some tests, if the problem also occurs with other record types.